# Inclusion of Weighted Function Spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be some normed space with norm $||\cdot||_X$. Additionally, consider a continuous increasing function $\eta: [0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ and set $\psi(x) := \eta(||x||_X)$. We refer to $\psi$ as the "weight function". Equipped with $X$ and $\psi$ we may define the following vector space
$$F_\psi(X):= \left\{ f:X \to \mathbb{R} : \sup_{x\in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{\psi(x)} <\infty \right\},$$
which can be seen as the space of real-valued maps over $X$ whose growth is controlled by $\psi: X \to (0,\infty)$. We equip $F_\psi(X)$ with the norm $||\cdot||_{F_\psi(X)}$ given by
$$||f||_{F_\psi(X)} = \sup_{x\in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{\psi(x)}.$$
Lastly, by observing that the set of real-valued bounded continuous functions over $X$, denoted by $C_b^0(X)$, is continuously embedded in $F_\psi(X)$, we define the **weighted function space** $\mathcal{B}_\psi(X)$ as the $||\cdot||_{F_\psi(X)}$-closure of $C_b^0(X)$.

Now, I would like to check whether I'm thinking correctly about the inclusions of these weighted function spaces. Let us assume that we have two weight functions $\psi_1: X \to (0,\infty)$ and $\psi_2: X \to (0,\infty)$ of the form introduced above such that
$$\psi_2(x) \geq \psi_1(x), \ \text{for all} \ x \in X.$$
Then, I reckon it's clear that
$$\sup_{x\in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{\psi_2(x)} \leq \sup_{x\in X} \frac{|f(x)|}{\psi_1(x)} \quad \text{and so,} \quad F_{\psi_1}(X) \subset F_{\psi_2}(X).$$
Moreover, whenever we have convergence with respect to $||\cdot||_{F_{\psi_1}(X)}$, we have convergence with respect to $||\cdot||_{F_{\psi_2}(X)}$. Hence,
$$\text{if} \quad \psi_2(x) \geq \psi_1(x), \ \text{for all} \ x \in X \quad \text{then} \quad \mathcal{B}_{\psi_1}(X) \subset \mathcal{B}_{\psi_2}(X).$$
Am I thinking correctly?